# Leaflet Map is not loading on ajax requested page, loads fine on hard refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet, progressive-web-apps

I currently have a PWA application running and I've added a 'custom' leaflet map in it. The PWA loads the pages via AJAX (IDK where), but that makes the leaflet map not loading. The moment I refresh (so f5), the map works just fine. Is there a way to have the map working properly?

All I do is having an js file that is being included in html, that file runs on document ready and initializes the map just like this:

```
map = L.map('map', {
    gestureHandling: true,
    center: [51.343695, 3.285927],
    zoom: 13
});
L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap.Mapnik').addTo(map);
```

Now that works just fine, but the ajax requested page (that just modifies the dom I think) doesn't work.

I tried to listen for ajax event ends, that doesn't work, nothing seems to... except 'hard refresh of the page', but that is not ideal at all...I'l using Laravel and I 'yield' scripts in the master.

Now for as far as I can tell, there is code that looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    'use strict';
    var options = {
        prefetch: true,
        prefetchOn: 'mouseover',
        cacheLength: 100,
        scroll: true,
        blacklist: '.default-link',
        forms: 'contactForm',
        onStart: {
            duration:150, // Duration of our animation
            render: function ($container) {
            $container.addClass('is-exiting');// Add your CSS animation reversing class
                $('.menu, .menu-hider').removeClass('menu-active');
                $('#preloader').removeClass('preloader-hide');
                return false;
            }
        },
        onReady: {
            duration: 10,
            render: function ($container, $newContent) {
                $container.removeClass('is-exiting');// Remove your CSS animation reversing class
                $container.html($newContent);// Inject the new content
                setTimeout(init_template, 0)//Timeout required to properly initiate all JS Functions.
                $('#preloader').removeClass('preloader-hide');
            }
        },
        onAfter: function($container, $newContent) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.menu').css('display','block');
                $('#preloader').addClass('preloader-hide');
            },150);
        }
    };
  var smoothState = $('#page').smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
   smoothState.clear();
});
```

I know I could just disable the ajax loading, but that would (I think) take away all the emersiveness away for a PWA?

Anyone who knows how to resolve this isse?

Comment: Can't see any ajax code there, so it's tricky to assess whether it's causing problems or not.

Comment: If I disable the above block, it works, else it doesn't, that's the really short issue

Comment: There's no ajax code there, though - just lots of options getting set, presumably for calls to some functions elsewhere which might include some ajax.

Comment: Would it help if I shared the demo of the PWA template I'm using?

Comment: _Might_ be a hidden map container issue, with your preloader hiding that container when the leaflet map is instantiated. What happens if you resize your window? Otherwise, as pointed out by peeebeee, you share far too less details for people to be able to help you without just blind guessing, unless they already know your exact stack (back, pwa framework, etc.). The more you leave in the way, the less people will be familiar with your environment and be able to help.

Comment: Okay, so I can't really share the link to the application (it's auth protected). But I did notice that the smoothState loads the application in the background and never, ever, changes the HTML. Thus I have other scripts that never get loaded that way. I think, if I just load the scripts at first load, it will work, as long as I make correct checks etc...